# Leap motion gesture add on libs?

Tags: leap-motion

Does anybody know any good leap motion gesture add on libs for python or javascript?

I want a clench and maybe a pinch/zoom gesture and didn't want to reinvent the wheel if they're already implemented somewhere.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: http://js.leapmotion.com/tutorials/gestures

Comment: Thanks man. I'm pretty familiar with all that. Was hoping for an already implemented version of those two gesture.

Comment: Were you able to add pinch or zoom gesture easily?